# SQL return ONLY the id's which exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I return the `check_type_dim_id`'s from the `Check_Type_Dimension` table that exist exclusively in the `Check_Type_Master` table?

I should only be returned 5 results but I'm getting 6 because of trying to join on the names:

```
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT check_type_id FROM check_type_master CTM WHERE 
 CTM.check_type_name = CTD.check_type_name)
```

The trouble is, the `check_type_dim_id` is an auditing table and can have duplicate names.

Table: `Check_Type_Dimension` contains the following info:

[image]

Table `Check_Type_Master` contains the following info:

[image]

Comment: Are you matching name field or check_type_name field

Comment: Your SQL with `EXISTS` does not seem to correspond to the schema. What is a `name` attribute? Could you provide us with the whole SQL and the expected result?

Comment: @Amit - sorry, when i say name, i mean check_type_name

Comment: @RadimBača - I have amended my extracted query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CTM.id
FROM check_type_master CTM 
JOIN Check_Type_Dimension CTD 
    ON CTM.check_type_name= CTD.check_type_name AND  CTM.check_type_id= CTD.check_type_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, that should solve your problem:

```
SELECT check_type_dim_id FROM Check_Type_Dimension
WHERE check_type_dim_id IN (SELECT check_type_dim_id FROM Check_Type_Master)
```

Generally, you can use `IN` operator with the subquery, to restrict some column to the set, returned by the subquery (it has to be one-column table).

Answer (score 0):

You should link the 2 tables in the EXISTS both on id & name.

Because you when the Dimension table has 2 different id's with the same name ("Member Charge") then your query would give extra results.

Example:

```
select check_type_dim_id
from Check_Type_Dimension CTD 
where exists (
   select 1
   from Check_Type_Master CTM
   where CTM.check_type_id = CTD.check_type_id
     and CTM.check_type_name = CTD.check_type_name
);
```